# php, sql, избавиться от цикла

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте. Не очень давно начал изучать php и столкнулся с некоторой проблемой.

Дано: 
    таблица с логами покупок в магазине (User, Cost, Date)
    таблица с пользователями (User, Money)

Первая таблица не имеет уникальных значений, поэтому имена пользователей повторяются.

Нужно из первой таблицы: получить имена всех пользователей, а также подсчитать потраченную сумму в определенный период
И добавить полученную сумму к балансу пользователю из второй таблицы. После чего эти записи удаляются.

С помощью php цикла я еще могу все это провернуть примерно так:

```
$query = $db->query(" SELECT `user`  FROM `table1` WHERE `date` >= $date GROUP BY `user` ");

if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
    while($res = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
        $db->query(" UPDATE `table2` SET `money` = `money` + (SELECT SUM(cost) FROM `table1` WHERE `user` = '$res['user']' AND `date` >= $date) WHERE `name` = '$res['user']' ");
    }
}
```

Но понимаю что это не лучший вариант.

Как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table2` T
  JOIN (SELECT user, SUM(cost) as M
          FROM `table1`
         WHERE `date` >= $date
         GROUP BY user
       ) A
    ON T.user=A.user
   SET T.`money` = T.`money` + A.M
```