# UPDATE запрос в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы:

```
table1
+---+------+
| a |   b  |
+---+------+
|   | vvvv |
|   | nnnn |
... 

table2
+---+------+
| c |   b  |
+---+------+
| 1 | vvvv |
| 2 | vvvv |
| 3 | nnnn |
| 1 | nnnn |
| 4 | kkkk |
| 2 | kkkk |
...
```

Нужно сделать запрос, чтоб в итоге в table1 проапдейтились поля так:

```
table1
+-----+------+
|  a  |   b  |
+-----+------+
| 1,2 | vvvv |
| 3,1 | nnnn |
...
```

т.е. что-то на подобие

```
table1.a = GROUP_CONCAT(table2.c SEPARATOR ',') where table1.b LIKE table2.b group by table2.b
```

Comment: Что  то в этом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/565658/194569 роде. В подзапросе ваш запрос получения списков

Comment: У меня обе таблицы очень большие и формировать временную таблицу на основе всех полей таблицы2 - нельзя. как то можно выбрать поля из table2.b = table1.b до группировки?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1, ( SELECT b, GROUP_CONCAT(c) d
                 FROM table2
                 -- WHERE b IN ('список', 'обновляемых', 'записей')
                 -- или (хуже, ибо фуллскан)
                 -- WHERE FIELD_IN_SET(b, 'список,обновляемых,записей')
                 GROUP BY b ) table3
SET table1.a = table3.d
WHERE table1.b = table3.b
```

Увы, порядок в обновляемом поле не гарантируется (нет вменяемого материала для выражения сортировки).

> не знаю как передать туда список нужных записей для фильтрации

Добавил условие отбора.

Comment: Порядок не нужен...

Comment: а нет возможности не группировать всю таблицу2? у меня таблица 1 и таблица2 большие

Comment: как-то во вложенный select передавать параметр table1.b

Comment: @VitalyM. Если вы хотите обновить всю таблицу, а не выборочно, то текущая группировка будет на порядок быстрее, чем подзапрос

Comment: @Mike table1 не вся обновляется, а только некоторые поля

Comment: @VitalyM. Вопрос не в полях, а в записях. Получение данных с группировкой в нужном разрезе быстрее, чем выполнение огромного количества мелких подзапросов получающих ту же сумму для каждого отдельного значения ключа

Comment: я не правильно написал, имел ввиду только для некоторых записей

Comment: @VitalyM. *имел ввиду только для некоторых записей* Ну так добавьте соотв. WHERE в группирующий подзапрос-то...

Comment: @Akina а как передать в группирующий подзапрос список значений table1.b, чтоб добавить в where?

Comment: @VitalyM. Список - это именно список? тогда тупо добавить в подзапрос `WHERE table2.b IN (список)`. Иначе объясняйте подробно, что имеется в виду под словом "список" - откуда, в какой форме и пр.

Comment: @Akina ну в tabl1 в столбце b содержатся значения 'vvvv' и 'nnnn' вот мне нужно только для них делать поиск во вложенном select. В  реальности table1 содержит много полей и при UPDATE у меня есть условие WHERE где я указываю фильтр для выборки нужных записей в которых нужно обновить значение поля table1.a и мне нужно из выбранных записей передать список значений поля table1.b во вложенный запрос

Comment: @VitalyM. Вот какая разница, в какой из таблиц фильтровать, если они один хрен при связывании равны?

Comment: ну в table1 у меня 1млн записей, я сделал WHERE и выбрал 10 записей, которые мне нужно обновить. В table2 у меня тоже 1 млн записей и выполнить группировку всех или только для тех, у которых значения table2.b = table1.b этих 10 записей разве нет разницы?

Comment: @VitalyM. Мужик, ну головой-то думай! ты чего хочешь? сперва мульён записей сгруппить, потом нужные 10 обновить? А я предлагаю сперва из этого мульёна выбрать сотню, их сгруппить и обновить. Боишься, что лишнее обновится? А, япона мать, ЧЕМ??? если ни для одной лишней записи подзапрос не даст запись для обновления...

Comment: @Akina Говорим об одном и том же. ) я тоже хочу сначала выбрать нужные и их сгрупить, а уж потом обновить в table1. Вот в твоем запросе `SELECT b, GROUP_CONCAT(c) d
                 FROM table2
                 GROUP BY b` нет выбора нужных записей, ты ж группируешь ВСЕ записи в таблице, а я хочу добавить туда фильтр where table2.b IN (...нужные записи из table1.b...)

Comment: но не знаю как передать туда список нужных записей для фильтрации

Comment: @VitalyM. *не знаю как передать туда список* Добавил в запрос.